# JavaScript Named functions and Event handlers regarding CPU consumption

Tags: javascript, dom-events, cpu-usage

After re-factoring my code as @FlorianMargaine suggested(in the JavaScript Chat conversation) , I got something that looks like the following:

```
body.addEventListener( 'mousedown', action1);
function action1(){
    //Start selecting event
    body.addEventListener( 'mousemove', selectOver);
}
function selectOver(e){
    //after the user has selected and done a mouse up event show a box:
    body.addEventListener( 'mouseup', showBox );
}
function showBox(e){
    //Show box
    box.addEventListener( 'click', actionAlert('clicked on interface after selected text') );
}
function actionAlert(d){
    alert(d);
}
```

The main problem is that I think that it uses a lot of CPU on the way, how can I minimize that?
I read a bit about the ability to remove the event handlers, is that the solution? and how can I integrate that solution efficiently to the code?

Comment: Are you sure that's what you're after? You're passing the return value of `actionAlert` to `addEventListener`, which is `undefined` and not a function.

Comment: This is a poorly-defined question. What are your goals? What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: *"I think that it uses a lot of CPU on the way"* -- *why* do you think that?  I'm not saying it's necessarily wrong to think that, but what tool made you think that?  Include that information in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be adding an event listener for `mouseup` on every `mousemove`, nor should you be **re-** registering your mousemove each time you mousedown Instead:

```
body.addEventListener( 'mousedown', action1, false);
function action1(){
    //Start selecting event
    body.addEventListener( 'mousemove', selectOver, false);
    body.addEventListener( 'mouseup', showBox, false );
    body.addEventListener( 'mouseup', function(){
      body.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', selectOver, false );
    });
}
function selectOver(e){
    // Not sure what this function is for.
}
function actionAlert(d){
    alert(d);
}
```

I've also added the explicit third parameter `false` to `addEventListener` as is required by some (all?) versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

(**edit** this is incorrect when using "addEventListener" but I'll leave it here as a historical curiosity:) You "action1" event handler re-binds the "mousemove" handler each time it's called. In turn, that handler binds a new handler for "mouseup".  After a little while, there'll be hundreds and hundreds of redundant handlers.

So, the lesson is: don't bind event handlers within other event handlers (unless you really have a good reason).  (**edit** — sorry; as I wrote above it's been pointed out that that's all incorrect.  I'm used to binding handlers with jQuery, and that library does not behave the same way.)

Also: your "showBox" function is, as written, binding the result of calling the "actionAlert" method, which has no return value. I think what you want is:

```
box.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  actionAlert('clicked on interface after selected text');
});
```

Comment: Actually `.addEventListener` will not add the same function more than once. From http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener : `If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same EventTarget with the same parameters the duplicate instances are discarded. `

Comment: Doing *redundant* bindings shouldn't be a problem unless you're using anonymous functions -- using the same function reference with `addEventListener` twice in a row [will *not* bind the function twice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners).  The lack of `removeEventListener` in the OP's code might be a problem, though.  Just wanted to point out the difference between *attaching redundant* bindings and *failure to remove* old bindings.

Comment: Ah, well sorry I'm just used to jQuery (which will add them) :-)